# "ERROR - C stack overflow" in Haskell sorting Strings

Tags: haskell

I have an "ERROR - C stack overflow" when I'm using my sort method in a where clause. But if I call the sort function separately (sort "aString") it works.
Any suggestions?

```
function :: String->String->Bool        
function w1 w2 
    |w1==w2     = True
    |otherwise  = False
    where (w1,w2) = (sort w1,sort w2)
```

Comment: Where does `sort` come from? Please edit your question and add all relevant imports.

Comment: sort is a fucntion that I created... It works on its own... 
sort "bca" returns  
abc

Comment: You should include the definition of `sort`, especially if it's a custom function of yours.

Comment: GHC has warnings that can point out this kind of issues, if you enable them. In this case you'd get a warning "name w1 shadows an earlier binding".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
where (w1,w2) = (sort w1,sort w2)
```

This definition is infinitely recursive (`w1 = sort w1 = sort (sort w1) = ...`). If you want to refer to the old bindings of `w1` and `w2` in your definition, you need to give your new bindings different names (and then use those new names when referring to the new values).

Something like this:

```
function :: String->String->Bool        
function w1 w2 
    |sortedW1 == sortedW2 = True
    |otherwise = False
    where (sortedW1, sortedW2) = (sort w1,sort w2)
```

Or of course just:

```
function :: String->String->Bool        
function w1 w2 
    |sort w1 == sort w2 = True
    |otherwise = False
```

Or even:

```
function :: String -> String -> Bool        
function w1 w2 = sort w1 == sort w2
```